# Ternary Operator not working in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I have a lightning:input field in which I need to use ternary operator in "value" as shown below but it does not work. I believe I am wrong with the syntax.

```
<lightning:input name="user" placeholder="Search" value="{!isCreate == 'true' ? !acc.user : !acc.owner}"/>
```

Where, acc.user and acc.owner has value. acc is iterating variable of List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression syntax for Aura components is `{!...}`. When you are inside of the expression (the `...` from before), `!` is the "not" [expression operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_operators.htm). For example, `{!!v.isRequired}` means "return true if isRequired is false".

Sometimes, people may think that the `!` is meant to denote the variable, as in:

```
`{!v.isRequired && !v.isEmpty}`
```

The documentation does call this out, but because it's only in one specific part, it's easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution actually worked for me. It had extra '!' which caused the problem:

```
<lightning:input name="user" placeholder="Search" value="{!isCreate == 'true' ? acc.user : acc.owner}"/>
```